# Unable to display array content

Tags: javascript

```
        var dataHolder = [
        {
            "letterA" : "Fruits",
            "letterB" : "Veges",
            "letterC" : "Meat"
        }
    ];
    console.log(dataHolder[0].letterA);
    var result = "";
    function getData(myLetter) {
        for (var i = 0; i < dataHolder.length; i++) {
           if(dataHolder[i][myLetter] === myLetter){
               console.log(dataHolder[i][myLetter]);
           }
           else{
               console.log("No data found");
           }
            }
        }
    getData("letterA");
```

This is my code and i'm just trying to match the content of the array with the passed parameter, but every time it's giving No data found as output and not the matching content, it seems i'm missing something very basic here.
Any help would be highly appreciated.Thanks!!

Comment: You are comparing the value in the key. For example if you call getData("letterA") the comparison will be between Fruits and letterA.

Comment: It is a json object use json functions like json.hasOwnProperty(key) to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You matching was wrong**.
 you are matching the `letters == fruites` .You should  check is the key exist or not ,that's enough  using [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

*Check this below. i was mention the error*

```js
var dataHolder = [{
  "letterA": "Fruits",
  "letterB": "Veges",
  "letterC": "Meat"
}];

var result = "";

function getData(myLetter) {
  for (var i = 0; i < dataHolder.length; i++) {
  console.log('this is the pblm  '+dataHolder[i][myLetter] +' != '+myLetter)
     if (dataHolder[i].hasOwnProperty(myLetter)) {
      console.log(dataHolder[i][myLetter]);
    } else {
      console.log("No data found");
    }
  }
}
getData("letterA");
```

For  your way use with `for...in`

```js
var dataHolder = [{
  "letterA": "Fruits",
  "letterB": "Veges",
  "letterC": "Meat"
}];

var result = "";

function getData(myLetter) {
  for (var i in dataHolder) {
    if (dataHolder[i].hasOwnProperty(myLetter)) {
      console.log(dataHolder[i][myLetter]);
    } else {
      console.log("No data found");
    }
  }
}
getData("letterA")
```

Comment: This works as long as the value of `dataHolder[i][myLetter]` is truthy. I'd probably tweak it a bit to use either the `in` operator o the `hasOwnProperty` method.

Comment: myLetter in dataHolder[i]

Comment: With this change you can find values like null, undefined, "", which where previously considered "no data" even when property existed. Okay, but not sure for what this can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing value with key that is wrong.

> The hasOwnProperty() method returns a boolean indicating whether the
>   object has the specified property as own (not inherited) property.

Use `hasOwnProperty` to check key exists or not.

```
dataHolder[i].hasOwnProperty(myLetter)
```

```js
var dataHolder = [
        {
            "letterA" : "Fruits",
            "letterB" : "Veges",
            "letterC" : "Meat"
        }
    ];
   
    var result = "";
    function getData(myLetter) {
        for (var i = 0; i < dataHolder.length; i++) {
       
           if(dataHolder[i].hasOwnProperty(myLetter)){
               console.log(dataHolder[i][myLetter]);
           }
           else{
               console.log("No data found");
           }
            }
        }
    getData("letterA");
```